# How to position this button on the right side?

Tags: html, css, sass, ionic2, ionic3

I hope you can help me with this problem. Since yesterday I’ve been trying to position this green button on the right side. And things like margin don’t work:(

**HTML**

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="rank">
    <ion-searchbar (input)="getItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
  <ion-list-header>
    Friends
  </ion-list-header>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-avatar item-start>
        <img src="img/fri.jpg">
      </ion-avatar>
      <h1>JanePrincess</h1>
      <h3>Iceland, Reykjavik </h3>
      <button ion-button color="rank" round>Add</button>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

**Here the button**

[image]

Comment: Since it's part of an `ion-item`, the `item-end` attribute should do the trick: `<button ion-button item-end ...>Add</button>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like you can see in **[the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#thumbnail-list)**, you can achieve that by using the `item-end` attribute in the button:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-avatar item-start>
      <img src="img/fri.jpg">
    </ion-avatar>
    <h1>JanePrincess</h1>
    <h3>Iceland, Reykjavik </h3>
    <button ion-button color="rank" round item-end>Add</button>
  </ion-item>

  <!-- ... -->

</ion-list>
```

Comment: Glad to hear that @ColinM. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `ion-item padding`.

```
<ion-item padding>
 <button default ion-button item-right color="rank" round >Add</button>
</ion-item>
```

You can use css as well.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you made the CSS file for the above problem, so try putting the following code into it:

```
button {
  color:green;
  position:relative;
  top:-43px;
  left: 410px;
}
```

To adjust the position of the button horizontally, just adjust `left` position accordingly.